# How to focus to a specific div when page reloads by pagination?

Tags: paginate-links

I´d like to focus on a div (#main.first), after clicking in wordpress pagination in my homepage.
I need that because my header (with image slider) is too big, and it steals focus from my posts list.
Could nor find nothing that helps.
Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got it with this script!
from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362026/wordpress-pagination-adding-an-anchor-link

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pagenavi a').each(function(i,a){$(a).attr('href',$(a).attr('href')+'#blog')});
});
</script>
```